# Center of the algebra of all linear transformations on a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove the following statement: "If $A$ is the algebra of all linear transformations on a linear space $L$, then the center of $A$ consists precisely of the scalar multiplications." The center of $A$ is its subset defined by $\{T\in A: TK=KT \text{ for every }K\in A\}$, which is a subalgabra of $A$. This is a question from the topology book of Munkres. Munkres suggests to use the following result: "Let $S$ be linear space, and let $x$ and $y$ be vectors in $S$ such that $x\neq 0$. Assume also that $y$ is not a scalar multiple of $x$. Then, there exists a linear transformation $T'$ on $S$ such that $T'(x)=0$ and $T'(y)\neq 0$."

My plan is the following: I know that the center of $A$ is a subalgebra. So, the hint applies to it. It is clear that the identity transformation is included in the center of $A$ and it is nonzero. If $T$ is not a scalar multiple of $I$ and is included in the center of $A$, I should be able to obtain a contradiction by applying the hint. But, I could not figure it out. If you can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You just need to apply the hint on $T(x) = y$ four your $T$ in the center

Comment: I cannot see the connection @interregno. Could you provide more detail please?

Comment: Suppose $T$ is in the center, and $T(x)$ is not a scalar multiple of $x$. Then apply the hint with $y = T(x)$. This shows for every $x$, $T(x)$ is some scalar multiple of $x$, but are they all multiples by the same value? Hint: use linearity, show for $x, y$ when $y$ is not a scalar multiple of $x$, using the hint. The case where $y = rx$ is even easier.